# Function stops code working

Tags: javascript, html

This function, obtained from http://alistapart.com/article/alternate, stops my JavaScript code working and I have no idea why. When this code is active the other functions stop doing anything. Can anyone help?

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
   var i, a, main;
   for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")<i>); i++) {
     if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
        && a.getAttribute("title")) {
       a.disabled = true;
   if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you post a link to your website ?

Comment: You should always check the date when looking at articles about JavaScript and web technologies in general. That article is *ancient*. I wrote an answer here about that typo years ago.

Comment: @Pointy it's poor quality code too, invoking `getElementsByTagName` within the loop!

Comment: @Alnitak I think *all* of the code samples have the same error. Sites like AListApart should really mark their super-old stuff with a warning header (and I think sometimes they actually do).

Answer (score 1):

Look at your JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

You've got `<i>` where you should have `[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `<i>` in your loop. There is fixed function

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
   var i, a, main, links;
   links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
   for(i=0; (a = links[i]); i++) {
     if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
        && a.getAttribute("title")) {
         a.disabled = true;
         if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
     }
   }
 }
```

I have also moved `document.getElementsByTagName("link")` to variable. It is more effective than searching DOM every loop.